# Could not normalize path for... location/proguard-android.txt'

Tags: android, mobile

Trying to execute 'react-native run-android' in cmd and here is what I got:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\mike\Documents\Android Studio\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 110
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\mike\Documents\Android Studio\AwesomeProject\android\C:UsersmikeAppDataLocalAndroidSdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 33.615 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Note: I've already added 'local.properties' with the associated sdk location.

Answer (score 1):

In your "local.properties" file ,change **sdk.dir=C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\AndroidSdk** to **sdk.dir=C:/Users/mike/AppData/Local/AndroidSdk**